# JSON newline delimited to regular json

Tags: arrays, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a variable with a JSON formatted library inside it like this:

```
things = [
    {“key”:”value”,”key1”:value1”}\n
    {“key”:”value”,”key1”:value1”}\n
    {“key”:”value”,”key1”:value1”}\n
    {“key”:”value”,”key1”:value1”}\n]
```

But instead of having the newline, I would like to make a normal JSON object with a comma delimiter. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Try `things.replace('\n', ',')`

Comment: This is definetly not valid JSON, even if we ommit, `\n` instead of `,`. You have: `”key1”:value1”` one `”` is missing as well.

Comment: @JussiNurminen I tried but I get ```AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'```

Comment: @PeterTrcka my bad that's a typo it does have the key/value pairs wrapped in double-quotes.

Comment: try this: `things[0].replace('\n', ',')`